# Qt 5.1 how to redist

Tags: c++, qt

I've an application written in C++ with QtCreator (Qt5.1). The toolset used is MinGW 4.8.0. I've added the following dlls:

- icudt51.dll
- icuin51.dll
- icuuc51.dll
- libboost_filesystem.dll ( boost 1.54.0 )
- libboost_system.dll
- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll

On my system the exe with this dlls works fine, but on another pc it crases at runtime

Are there some other dependencies?

Comment: in case you're afraid of missing a depedency, you can always use this tool: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ Not only it will detect link-time dependencies, but it can also profile the program and track any dynamic library loading (useful for qt image plugins).

Comment: in this case it doesn't help because Qt use dynamic dll load for example for plugins

Comment: I just said it _can_ track dynamic loading through profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following link. It contains how to find dependencies etc.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

For now test by addin.
qt.conf and 'plugins' folder and MINGWM10.DLL to your exe path.

Comment: resolved i need to copy the folder plugins/platform inside platform, at the same root of the exe

Comment: MINGWM10.dll isn't needed... well on my system doesn't exist